# The score in my python game doesn't add up correctly

Tags: python

So I've been making a little game just to test myself and I can't seem to make the score update at all, could I please have some help? EDIT: Sorry for being unspecific with the question, what the problem is when the Asteroid goes past the screen, the first one gives ten points but then after that the score doesn't go up? I think it's a problem with this segment of code, I'd want it so after the asteroid as passed below the screen, the asteroid is deleted and then it adds 10 points to the score. I'm the Livewires module as well.

```
class Asteroid(games.Sprite):
    """
    A asteroid which falls through space.
    """ 
    image = games.load_image("asteroid_med.bmp")
    speed = 1

    def __init__(self, x, y = 10):
        """ Initialize a asteroid object. """
        super(Asteroid, self).__init__(image = Asteroid.image,
                                    x = x, y = y,
                                    dy = Asteroid.speed)
        self.score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, color  = color.green,
                                top = 5, right = games.screen.width-10)

        games.screen.add(self.score)


    def update(self):
        """ Check if bottom edge has reached screen bottom. """
        self.add_score()

    def add_score(self):
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height:
            self.score.value+=10
            self.score.right = games.screen.width - 10
            self.destroy()
```

Comment: It doesnt appear that you have defined score as a parameter of the class

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot How would I do that, if you don't mind tell me

Comment: Right below where you do the same for speed. Or as someone mentions below in a global variable

Answer (score 0):

you're destroying the object after incrementing the score.

Comment: Ahhh, So how would I increment in the score and then it updates after the asteroid is destroyed?, would it be possible to just increment the score and have the asteroids pass the screen without being destroyed?

Comment: i'd say you should use a global variable for the score and not an instanced variable at the asteroid. - [cK]Senior_Heuser

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better design to have the asteroid dispatch an event or something that would update the score in a global object. Currently, the asteroid itself is keeping track of the score, which doesn't work because it gets destroyed.

Comment: And then have the value in the score read from the global object?

Comment: The only thing that needs to be defined in the Asteroid object is the number of points it's worth. All of the scorekeeping should be tracked by whatever object is spawning the asteroids. 

Events are the way to go. I'm not exactly sure how they work in python, but you should research them.

Answer (score 0):

You destroy the object after updating its score, and it appears that the score is an instance variable of the object. You should try making the score a static member, rather than creating a global variable. This will let your score persist through every instance of the Asteroid.

http://linuxwell.com/2011/07/21/static-variables-and-methods-in-python/